# What unit system is used in Feynman's Lectures on Physics, Pt. 2

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, units, si-units

In part II, lecture 18, of [Feynman's Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_18.html), on Table 18-1 Feynman writes Ampère's law as
$$
c^2 \nabla \times \vec{B} = \frac{\vec{j}}{\epsilon_0} + \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
$$

What unit system is this in?  It's not obviously Gaussian, which states,
$$
c \nabla \times \vec{B} = 4 \pi \vec{j} + \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
$$

Nor does it appear to be formulated in  SI, which states,

$$
\frac{1}{\mu_0} \nabla \times \vec{B} = \vec{j} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
$$

Comment: This appears to be using SI convention, taking advantage of the relation $\epsilon_0\mu_0 c^2 = 1$

Comment: @BySymmetry Shouldn't that be an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply
$$
c^2 \nabla \times \vec{B} = \frac{\vec{j}}{\epsilon_0} + \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}
$$
through by $\epsilon_0$, and substitute in the identity
$$
c^2 = \frac1{\epsilon_0\mu_0} ,
$$
and it will be quickly revealed to be in the SI form you quote.